# linq to entities: nested .Any()

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

In a repository I need to search a contact (c)'s features for a collection of other features defined in a searchCriteria (sc). The Expression Func looks like this:

```
// no Problem from here --->  
c => c.firstName.StartsWith(sc.FirstName)  
  && c.lastName.StartsWith(sc.LastName)  
  && c.addressData.Any(a => a.City.StartsWith(sc.City))  
  && c.addressData.Any(a => a.StreetAddr.StartsWith(sc.Street))  
  && c.addressData.Any(a => a.ZIPCode.StartsWith(sc.ZipCode))  
  && c.visit.Any(v=> v.vStartDate >= sc.VisitTimeIntervalStart)  
  && c.visit.Any(v => v.vStartDate <= sc.VisitTimeIntervalEnd)  
  // <-- to here  but this ->  
  && c.contact2feature.Any( 
      c2f => sc.FeaturePattern.Any(       
         ` fp => fp.Item1.featureID == c2f.feature.featureID))     
// thows:  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException  
// Inner: Unable to process the type System.Tuple 2[], because it has no known mapping to the value layer.
```

Comment: **Feeling olympic today?** You're brave to do do such things with EF. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `sc.FeaturePattern` appears to be a `Tuple`, which means it's not part of your entity model/EDMX. So LINQ to Entities doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. But you can pretty easily work around that:

```
// extract scalar values from tuple
var featureIds = sc.FeaturePattern.Select(fp => fp.Item1.featureId);

// now do query
// ...
c => c.firstName.StartsWith(sc.FirstName)  
  && c.lastName.StartsWith(sc.LastName)  
  && c.addressData.Any(a => a.City.StartsWith(sc.City))  
  && c.addressData.Any(a => a.StreetAddr.StartsWith(sc.Street))  
  && c.addressData.Any(a => a.ZIPCode.StartsWith(sc.ZipCode))  
  && c.visit.Any(v=> v.vStartDate >= sc.VisitTimeIntervalStart)  
  && c.visit.Any(v => v.vStartDate <= sc.VisitTimeIntervalEnd)  
  // <-- to here  but this ->  
  && c.contact2feature.Any( 
      c2f => featureIds.Contains(       
          fid => fid == c2f.feature.featureID))
```